# Maximum rcpt groups count in civimail

Tags: civimail

When trying to compose an email via CiviMail addressing many groups it seems the interface smashes some groups when adding new ones. Our users can't see a reproducible pattern.

So my question is: Are there any limits regardarding the count of groups in the selector or the estimated recipients count?

Or do you have any other ideas what could cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not appear to happen since upgrading to 4.7.7.